# Duplicate line command in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to duplicate a line in Visual Studio 2005? I briefly had ReSharper installed and then I used `CTRL+D`.

What I liked was that it didn't put that line into the clipboard memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in command (afaik), but Christophe Herreman explains how to create a macro to do it here: ["Duplicate line command for Visual Studio"](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/52)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution as well.  A quick keyboard shortcut that will work on every IDE on Windows will be to use the HOME, END trick.

```
Move cursor to end of the line (Press End)
Press Shift+Home to highlight current line
Press Ctrl + C to copy
Press End.  Press Enter
Press Ctrl + V to paste.
```

Comment: L
O
L
Thanks, hadn't thought about that. ;)